# ActiveJob: how to do simple operations without a full blown job class?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, delayed-job, rails-activejob

With `delayed_job`, I was able to do simple operations like this:

`@foo.delay.increment!(:myfield)`

**Is it possible to do the same with Rails' new ActiveJob?** (without creating a whole bunch of job classes that do these small operations)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*ActiveJob* is merely *an abstraction on top of various background job processors*, so **many capabilities depend on which provider you're actually using**. But I'll try to not depend on any backend.

Typically, a job provider consists of **persistence mechanism** and **runners**. When offloading a job, you write it into persistence mechanism in some way, then later one of the runners retrieves it and runs it. So the question is: can you express your job data in a format, compatible with **any action** you need?

#### That will be tricky.

Let's define what is a job definition then. For instance, it could be a single method call. Assuming this syntax:

```
Model.find(42).delay.foo(1, 2)
```

We can use the following format:

```
{
  class: 'Model',
  id: '42', # whatever
  method: 'foo',
  args: [
    1, 2
  ]
}
```

Now how do we build such a hash from a given call and enqueue it to a job queue?

First of all, as it appears, we'll need to define a class that has a `method_missing` to catch the called method name:

```
class JobMacro
  attr_accessor :data
  def initialize(record = nil)
    self.data = {}
    if record.present?
      self.data[:class] = record.class.to_s
      self.data[:id]    = record.id
    end
  end
  def method_missing(action, *args)
    self.data[:method] = action.to_s
    self.data[:args] = args
    GenericJob.perform_later(data)
  end
end
```

The job itself will have to reconstruct that expression like so:

```
data[:class].constantize.find(data[:id]).public_send(data[:method], *data[:args])
```

Of course, you'll have to define the `delay` macro on your model. It may be best to factor it out into a module, since the definition is quite generic:

```
def delay
  JobMacro.new(self)
end
```

It does have some limitations:

- Only supports running jobs on persisted ActiveRecord models. A job needs a way to reconstruct the callee to call the method, I've picked the most probable one. You can also use marshalling, if you want, but I consider that unreliable: the unmarshalled object may be invalid by the time the job gets to execute. Same about "GlobalID".
- It uses Ruby's reflection. It's a tempting solution to many problems, but it isn't fast and is a bit risky in terms of security. So use this approach cautiously.
- Only one method call. No procs (you could probably do that with `ruby2ruby` gem). Relies on job provider to serialize arguments properly, if it fails to, help it with your own code. For instance, `que` uses JSON internally, so whatever works in JSON, works in `que`. Symbols don't, for instance.

Things will break in spectacular ways at first.
**So make sure to set up your debugging tools before starting off.**

---

An example of this is [Sidekiq's backward (Delayed::Job) compatibility extension for ActiveRecord](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/blob/master/lib/sidekiq/extensions/active_record.rb).

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, this is currently not supported. You can easily simulate this feature using a custom-defined proxy-job that accepts a model or instance, a method to be performed and a list of arguments.

However, for the sake of code testing and maintainability, this shortcut is not a good approach. It's more effective (even if you need to write a little bit more of code) to have a specific job for everything you want to enqueue. It forces you to think more about the design of your app.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a gem that can help you with that https://github.com/cristianbica/activejob-perform_later. But be aware that I believe that having methods all around your code that might be executed in workers is the perfect recipe for disaster is not handled carefully :)